# Is there any added value to running collators that are not authoring blocks?

Tags: parachain

What is the value of a collator connected to the parachain network that is not producing blocks?

If there is one, are there any best practices to incentivise more nodes on the network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no value in running collators that are not authoring blocks.

Comment: Thanks Basti! I am just trying to add all the questions I remember being asked on element